# How to checkout a file into previous revision in egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

could please anybody tell us if it is possible and if it is not, what is the best alternative to do it ? This is how it would be done in command line :
`git checkout  HEAD~1 -- path/to/file`

But if the project is big, navigating to that file in cmd can be annoying ....

Comment: workaround: Right-click on the file in Project Explorer or a similar view in Eclipse, then select "Copy Qualified Name" and paste that to the command line.

Comment: Hey taht's cool, I've never noticed of Copy qualified name, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with EGit version 1.0 or higher (it might also be possible with earlier versions, but 1.0 is the first version I noticed the feature).

1. Right-click on the file you wish replace with an earlier commit, and select *Replace With -> Commit...*
2. You will be presented with a list of commits to choose from. Select the commit you wish to replace the file with.

Answer (score 5):

This is available in EGit 2.0:

Select the file(s)/folder(s) you want to replace with another version
and use any of the commands:

- "Replace with > Commit..."
- "Replace with > HEAD revision"
- "Replace with > Branch, Tag, or Reference"
- "Replace with > File in Git Index"

Comment: When I do this, the file is automatically added to the index. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The “File in Git Index” item is not available in EGit 4.x on Mac OS X. How can I restore a *single* file instead of the whole commit with EGit 4.x?

Comment: @zedoo I do not think so, but you can remove it from the index afterwards with “Team” → “Remove from Index” in EGit 4.x.

Answer (score -4):

I know you can reset your full history to a previous commit. I don't know about just one file.

This is why I don't recommend anyone using Egit. You will out grow it in a few days of usage.

Comment: At version 1.0, EGit has become pretty mature. The most important git features are now fully supported.